# how to include and use math.js

Tags: javascript, math.js

I am trying to use math.js (http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/inv.html) but I can't see how to include it in an HTML file.

I have read that you can include it by adding this to the file:

```
var math = require('mathjs');
```

but that didn't work for me

I realize this sounds like a really stupid question but I have tried to figure it out myself and have not been successful.

To answer my question just show a complete HTML file (not just a bit of code from one) that successfully uses math.js

Thanks

I tried what Alexander O'Mara suggested and I got this:

```
/** * Math.js can easily be extended with functions and variables using the * `import` function. The function `import` accepts a module name or an object * containing functions and variables. */ // load math.js (using node.js) var math = require('../index'); /** * Define new functions and variables */ math.import({ myConstant: 42, hello: function (name) { return 'hello, ' + name + '!'; } }); // defined methods can be used in both JavaScript as well as the parser print(math.myConstant * 2); // 84 print(math.hello('user')); // 'hello, user!' print(math.eval('myConstant + 10')); // 52 print(math.eval('hello("user")')); // 'hello, user!' /** * Import the math library numbers.js, https://github.com/sjkaliski/numbers.js * The library must be installed first using npm: * npm install numbers */ try { // load the numbers.js library var numbers = require('numbers'); // import the numbers.js library into math.js math.import(numbers, {wrap: true, silent: true}); if (math.fibonacci) { // calculate fibonacci print(math.fibonacci(7)); // 13 print(math.eval('fibonacci(7)')); // 13 } } catch (err) { console.log('Warning: To import numbers.js, the library must ' + 'be installed first via `npm install numbers`.'); } /** * Import the math library numeric.js, http://numericjs.com/ * The library must be installed first using npm: * npm install numeric */ try { // load the numeric.js library var numeric = require('numeric'); // import the numeric.js library into math.js math.import(numeric, {wrap: true, silent: true}); if (math.eig) { // calculate eigenvalues of a matrix print(math.eval('eig([1, 2; 4, 3])').lambda.x); // [5, -1]; // solve AX = b var A = math.eval('[1, 2, 3; 2, -1, 1; 3, 0, -1]'); var b = [9, 8, 3]; print(math.solve(A, b)); // [2, -1, 3] } } catch (err) { console.log('Warning: To import numeric.js, the library must ' + 'be installed first via `npm install numeric`.'); } /** * By default, the function import does not allow overriding existing functions. * Existing functions can be overridden by specifying option `override: true` */ math.import({ pi: 3.14 }, { override: true }); print(math.pi); // returns 3.14 instead of 3.141592653589793 /** * Helper function to output a value in the console. Value will be formatted. * @param {*} value */ function print (value) { var precision = 14; console.log(math.format(value, precision)); }
```

Comment: http://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html

Comment: Well, did you include `require.js` first?

Comment: That's the commonjs (node) way, perhaps you want the browser examples.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to you is to include `math.js` from a CDN:

```
<head>
    <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
</head>
```

Every script you need, search in Google for the CDN (in this example [`mathjs cdn`](http://www.google.com/search?q=mathjs+cdn), and include it to your page HEAD. This way you don't need to download anything to your server.

---

## More info about CDN:

- [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

> The Google Hosted Libraries is a stable, reliable, high-speed,
>   globally available content distribution network for the most popular,
>   open-source JavaScript libraries.
>
> Google works directly with the key stakeholders for each library
>   effort and accepts the latest versions as they are released.

- [cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/)

> Everyone loves the Google CDN right? Even Microsoft runs their own
>   CDN.  The problem is, they only host the most popular libraries.  We
>   host all the popular libraries - JavaScript, CSS, SWF, images, etc! 
>   Join us now on GitHub!

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use require in the browser. You should try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="math.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // use math.js
    math.sqrt(-4); // 2i
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

check the docs: http://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, see my edited question for my results

Answer (score 3):

They have a restful API you can use, http://api.mathjs.org. OR you should be able to just download the production from [here](http://mathjs.org/download.html) and include that in your JS.

In your head tag:

```
<script src="math.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Import

```
import { create, all } from 'mathjs'
```

init

```
const math = create(all,  {})
```

usage

```
console.log(math.sqrt(-4).toString())
```

Comment: Thank you, working perfectly, React Js, NextJs. Using this for calc.ai

Comment: nothing else I tried worked, but this worked really well

Answer (score 2):

In the year 2022, you can use

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.2.0/math.js'></script>
```

inside the `head` tag.
Once `math.js` is loaded, the global symbol `math` representing it can be used to do many kinds of mathematic computations once considered hard or impossible to perform.

It is possible to demonstrate the use of `math.js` that can run right here.
Let me try to show runnable code on this web page as an answer.

```js
function print (value) {
  const precision = 14
  console.log(math.format(value, precision))
}

print(math.round(math.e, 3))   // 2.718
print(math.atan2(3, -3) / math.pi )
print(math.log(10000, 10))
print(math.sqrt(-4))
print(math.pow([[-1, 2], [3, 1]], 2))     // [[7, 0], [0, 7]]
print(math.evaluate('12 / (2.3 + 0.7)'))
print(math.evaluate('12.7 cm to inch'))    // 5 inch
print(math.evaluate('sin(45 deg) ^ 2'))    // 0.5
print(math.evaluate('det([-1, 2; 3, 1])')) // -7

// matrix inversion
var mat_a = [[1, 2], [3, -4]]
var b1 = [[2], [1]]
var mat_ai = math.inv(mat_a) 
// check the inversion; OK
print( math.multiply(mat_a, mat_ai) )
// get sol A.x=b; x=?
var x = math.multiply(mat_ai, b1)
print( {x} )  // solution x
print( math.multiply(mat_a, x) ) // expect b; OK

// use of linear-eq solve
// Matrix must be a lower triangular matrix if use `lsolve()`
var x2 = math.lusolve(mat_a, b1)
print( {x2} ); // OK

// Use lup(A) instead of A
// This is preferable method
var x3 = math.lusolve(math.lup(mat_a), b1)
print( {x3} ); // OK

// LU decomposition
var m = [[2, 1], [1, 4]]
var r = math.lup(m)
print({r}) //ok {'r': {'L': [[1, 0], [0.5, 1]], 'U': [[2, 1], [0, 3.5]], 'p': [0, 1]}}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.2.0/math.js'></script>
```