# javascript including math.js

Tags: javascript, import, include, math.js

I am trying to call the Math.matrix() function, and I am quite certain I am not importing the file correctly into my javascript code.  I have read through the StackOverflow question ["how to include and use math.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416492/how-to-include-and-use-math-js):  and given that advice, I have the following :

```html
<HTML >
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
    <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.1/math.js>
    </script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" >
       function rotate_clockwise(){
          /* code skipped */
          matrix = Math.matrix(matrix, rotationmatrix);
      }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

where the cdns reference I have taken from this [link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjs)

But on run when `rotate_clockwise` is called via slider the chrome 68 debugger states `Uncaught type error : Math.matrix is not a function`, so I do believe I am not including this file correctly.

My base assumption is that including a file once, in one set of script tags, is enough for any javascript function to use this library, which resides within a different set of script tags.

Thanks so much for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: try this <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.1/math.js">

Comment: Thank you Chris, much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`math.matrix(...)`](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/matrix.html)--lower case `math` since [`Math` is a standard JS library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).